# Displaying results from an Oracle query based on user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I am trying to query the records for a specific ID in an Oracle table based on what the user inputs.

Here is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('dbuser/dbpassword@oracle_host/service_ID')
cur = con.cursor()
id_number = raw_input('What is the ID Number?')
cur.execute('select id, info from oracle_table_name where id=:id_number')
for result in cur:
    print "test", result
cur.close()
con.close()
```

The following error pops up: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound`

When I remove the user input and the variable substitution and run the query, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:id_number` in your SQL is a parameter (variable). You need to provide its value.
`execute` method accepts parameters as the second argument.

Example:

`query = "select * from some_table where col=:my_param"
cursor.execute(query, {'my_param': 5})`

Check the documentation at http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.execute

Comment: For a set value for my_param, that worked great. The other part of the question was in regards to taking dynamic user input and using that as the my_param value to achieve the same results.

Comment: replace "5" of the example (in the parameter dictionary) here with your dynamic value, which is `{'my_param': id_number}`.

Answer (score 1):

I assigned a name to the user_value:

```
user_value = raw_input('What is the ID Number?')
```

And then referenced it in the execute statement:

```
cur.execute(query, {'id': (user_value)})
```

Thanks to Radoslaw-Roszkowiak for the assist!!